# How to Print a shuffled array without brackets and commas in swift

Tags: swift

How do i Print a shuffled array without brackets and commas in swift?
For example if I create an array:

```
var names = ["john", "connor", "Sarra"]
print(names.shuffled())
```

It will print the names array with commas and brackets - I want it to be printed without anything !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `joined(separator:)` method:

```
var names = ["john", "connor", "Sarra"]
print(names.shuffled()) // ["john", "connor", "Sarra"]
print(names.shuffled().joined(separator: "")) // connorSarrajohn
print(names.shuffled().joined(separator: " ")) // connor Sarra john
```

Comment: no need to pass an empty string `joined()`

Comment: What he ⬆ said.

Comment: tried that but receiving this error
Referencing instance method 'joined(separator:)' on 'BidirectionalCollection' requires the types 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') and 'String' be equivalent

Comment: @Mike ask a new question with that specific problem since this one was closed

Comment: `print(names.shuffled().joined()) // connorSarrajohn` btw not my downvote